# ¿Como puedo mantener la url después de enviar un formulario?

Tags: python, flask

necesito saber como mantener una url después de enviar un formulario en Python Flask.

```
@app.route('/signup', methods=["GET","POST"])
def signup():
    if '?ref=' in request.url:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            email_sign = request.form.get("email")
            password_sign = request.form.get("password")
            confirm_password_sign = request.form.get("confirm-password")
            secure_password_sign = sha256_crypt.encrypt(str(password_sign))
```

Mi problema es que al enviarlo no detecta que '?ref' está en la url ya que la url deja de ser esta:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/signup?ref=Ejemplo
```

Y pasa a ser esta:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/signup
```

Por lo tanto no funciona, como lo puedo hacer? Gracias.

Comment: Realmente es cómo mantener los parámetros en el GET al enviar una petición POST

Comment: @Alfabravo Entiendo que dices pero no sé como hacerlo, podrías explicarmelo?

Comment: `if request.args.get('ref'):`